# R, sink/cat: Output something else than numbers?

Tags: r, cat, sink

I'm rather new to R and I guess there's more than one thing inadequate practice in my code (like, using a for loop). I think in this example, it could be solved better with something from the apply-family, but I would have no idea how to do it in my original problem - so, if possible, please let the for-loop be a for-loop. If something else is bad, I'm happy to hear your opinion.

But my real problem is this. I have:

```
name <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a","a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b","b", "b", "b","b", "b", "b") 
class <- c("c1", "c1", "c1", "c2", "c2", "c2", "c3", "c3", "c3","c1", "c1", "c1", "c2", "c2", "c2", "c3", "c3", "c3")
value <- c(100, 33, 80, 90, 80, 100, 100, 90, 80, 90, 80, 100, 100, 90, 80, 99, 80, 100)
df <- data.frame(name, class, value)
df
```

And i want to print it out. I use sink as well as hwriter (to output it as a html) later on. I get the problem with both, so I hope it's caused by the same and it's enough if we solve it for sink. That's the code:

```
sink("stuff.txt")

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    cat(" Name:")
    cat(df$name[i-1])
    cat("\n")
    cat(" Class:")
    cat(df$class[i-1])
    cat("\n")
}

sink()
file.show("stuff.txt")
```

Part of the output I get is something like:

```
 Name:1
 Class:1
 Name:1
 Class:2
 Name:1
 Class:2
```

On the other hand, the output I want should be like:

```
 Name:a
 Class:c1
 Name:a
 Class:c2
 Name:a
 Class:c2
```

Comment: Your data.frame command is creating factors. If you don't want them, use `df <- data.frame(name, class, value, stringsAsFactors=F)`

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `cat` was printing numbers was that your character variables were converted to "factors" when you put them in the data.frame. This is the default behavior for data.frames. It is often a more efficient way to store the values because it converts each string value to a unique integer value. That's why you see numbers when you cat the value.

If you don't want to use factors in your data.frame, you can use

```
df <- data.frame(name, class, value, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

and this will keep the values as characters. Alternatively, you can convert to character when you print

```
cat(as.character(df$name[i-1]))
```